# JSON.DeserializeUntyped: Can I infer anything from the Object returned?

Tags: apex, json

Given a JSON response from a remote API call, I can use JSON.DeserializeUntyped to get an Object, which can then be cast to another type as needed.  For example:

```
String jsonResponse = makeAPICall(); //defined elsewhere
Object objResponse = JSON.DeserializedUntyped(jsonResponse);

// if I expect a list of something:
list<Object> responseList = (list<Object>)objResponse;

// but if I expect a map:
map<string, Object> responseMap = (map<string, Object>)objResponse;
```

Is there any way of determining anything about Object?  I can't find any documentation on the type.  In my particular case, I need to know if the json response contains a list or a map... I don't even need to know what kind of list or map, since there are only two possibilities for the method I'm calling (a list of objects, or a map describing an error).  Possibilities I've considered:

- peek at the beginning of the json string
- attempt to cast inside a try-catch block

Not a fan of either approach, was hoping for some way of checking the type (expecting, for example, `Object`, `List<Object>`, or `Map<string, Object>`), does such a thing exist?  Is this just bad API design?

Comment: Yep, you can do (obj instanceof MyClass) etc

Comment: Wow, I'd forgotten that apex supports the instanceOf operator.  Confirmed, e.g., (obj instanceOf list<Object>) works perfectly.  Please make that an answer so I can accept it :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use the instanceof operator:

```
if (obj instanceof MyClass) //...
else if (obj instanceof MyObject__c) //...
else if (obj instanceof Map<String,String> //...
```

I'd reckon there's still a desirable future Apex feature here as there's no reliable way to get the Type from an object instance.

Answer (score 2):

Ideally you shouldn't need such checks, and its BAD API design to consume a resource which can return either a MAP or LIST. Anyway, this code snippet shows how to check for both map and list

```
Object mapObj = JSON.deserializeUntyped ('{"Key1" : "Value1"}');
System.debug('Is Map: ' + (mapObj instanceof Map<String, Object>) );

Object arrObj = JSON.deserializeUntyped ('["Apple", "Orange"]');
System.debug('Is List: ' + (arrObj instanceof List<Object>) );
```